# How to reply back a user with his/her name using Dialogflow?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want to know how to reply back a user with his/ her name?
For example:

**AppName**: Hello, may I ask your name?

**User**: My name is John

**AppName**: Welcome John to $appname

I want to do this without webhook or fulfillment. I just want to do with *Dialogflow*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an Intent in Dialogflow that takes the user's name as a parameter. You then reference this parameter using `$parameter_name` in the reply string. If you want this maintained for future calls in your conversation, you can add an outgoing context. It might look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank You
But I am facing another problem.
There are some names like my name. But it's not coming in parameters

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but this sounds like a different issue. If so, it is best asked as a separate question, providing as many details as you can.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use it in other intents taking this context as an input, you have to refer to it as #context_name.parameter_name like this :

[image: dialogflow name context]

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would send a permission request from the fulfillment code, but you can not do this from Dialogflow at the moment. You can only trigger a permission request from the fulfillment. By the way, even if the feature existed, neither Dialogflow or Actions on Google would save the info for you. So you would have to ask for it in each session. If you get it in the fulfillment you will need to ask for it only once because you can save it.

Comment: No, I don't want to save anyone's name. Even I don't require. If I'll be requiring then I will build fulfillment. I just want to reply back a user with it's name. That's it.