# How can i customize google home expressions while building my app?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

I would like to make input to Google Home, not as a intent, more as a answer. I'm using Dialogflow

Example :

```
Home : "What is your name ?"
Me   : "John"
Home : "Nice to meet you John"
```

Which function am I supposed to use to make an understandable input? How can I store this in a variable?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "understable"? And, to be clear, are you trying to use Dialogflow for this, or something else? (Or don't you care?)

Comment: understandable* Sorry ( Something that google home can understand)

And yeh im using DialogFlow :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027819/how-to-reply-back-a-user-with-his-her-name-using-dialogflow

Comment: The name was just an example, actually i dont care about name.

The purpose is to ask a code " Give me your secret code" " my code is 1 2 3 4" juste just i will compare what i say and a code in a variable, exit if the code is false, continue if it's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an intent to expect your answer. 
Then create you select part of your "user says" expression to be your answer, like the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKLzb.png) shows.

Define your [action and parameter name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukaF2.png).

Then on your fulfillment you can can get it like this:

```
let name = app.getArgument('userName');
```